# CEF closing/resizing issues inside a big application plugin

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, 64-bit, chromium-embedded

I'm writing a plugin for a big x64 application in C++. I want the plugin to open a dialog and show a web view of my site.
I'm been able to use WKWebView in macOS and it works well. On Windows I'm evaluating CEF https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef (please let me know of any alternative, ideally I would like it to be Webkit-based).

Let's say the application framework that is hosting my plugin has already created a window for my plugin and has it's own message loop, so I can only receive events in a sort of WindowProc. I can also get the HWND of the window.

My implementation is inspired by cefsimple example, because cefclient is way too complicated. I've implemented the subprocess architecture with the external executable and everything works fine until it's rendering the client area of the window. Then I have problems with closing the window (it crashes) and resizing the window interactively (the window frame is resized but the web view in the client area does not resize).

I've tried all possible combinations, but I've run out of ideas. Namely:

- If I use CefRunMessageLoop() the web view is rendered correctly but the main application does not process the UI events like close window button. Resize does not work.
- If I call CefDoMessageLoopWork() myself once in a while (from WindowProc) the web view is rendered correctly and it processes the close button, but it crashes. Resize does not work.
- If I use settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = true the web view is rendered correctly and I can close the window without crash. The destructor of the window calls CefShutdown(). But if I try to reopen the window it crashes! Are CefInitialize and CefShutdown allowed to be called only once?
  And resizing still does not work. I don't understand why in the cefsimple example resizing works and in my window it does not work.

Besides message processing issues, probably I'm not closing the browser correctly, any advice? Why is so complicated? WKWebView is so straighforward!

Answer (score 0):

There is no error message, no stack trace, no source code, no OS/CEF version - I doubt this question can be answered.

I can only tell you how to close browser cleanly: call CefShutdown at the right time (see cefclient/cefsimple examples) and do not keep any references to CEF objects when calling shutdown.